# How to get variable from statefulwidget class to state class in dart flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

This is my flutter code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Navbar extends StatefulWidget {
  int tabIndex;
  Navbar(this.tabIndex);

  _NavbarState createState() => _NavbarState();
}

class _NavbarState extends State<Navbar> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
// I need to get tabIndex here
}
```

I need to get tabIndex in second class, thank you so much for your answers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a tabIndex variable in your `State` class and initialize it in your `initState` with `widget.tabIndex`.

```
class _NavbarState extends State<Navbar> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
// I need to get tabIndex here
int tabIndex;

 @override
 void initState() {
  tabIndex= widget.tabIndex;
  super.initState();
 }
}
```

Or you can just call it inside `build` method with `widget.tabIndex`.